# jQuery - if an img is inside a cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

```
$("#user_status").html('<img src="img/check_01.png">'); // puts img into a cell
```

Now, I want to execute a code IF that img is placed into that cell using PHP.

```
if ($("#user_status").html('<img src="img/check_01.png">')) 
// syntax error
```

What is the correct way, please.

Comment: How's that PHP at all? This looks like jQuery.

Comment: That is JS and jQuery. Where is PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ($("#user_status").html() == '<img src="img/check_01.png">'){
// do something
}
```

**EDIT:** (Thanks to @Esailija)
It is much safer to use something like this, which will work across all browsers including IE, if you are just checking for the presence of an image.

```
if(typeof($("#user_status").find('img').attr('src')) !== 'undefined'){
//do something
}
```

This **works** across all major browsers.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zheT3/1/

**[(Reference)](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html1)**

If you are trying to use PHP, you could use the [SimpleHtmlDom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to manipulate and compare values of the html.

```
$html = your_html;
$text = $html->find('div[id=user_status]', 0)->innertext;
if($text == '<img src="img/check_01.png">'){
//do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Solved. Excuse me for my confusion.

Comment: I added the PHP method anyway, if you are interested.

Comment: Extremely fragile, IE would report false for it for example.

Comment: ThankYou, DarkX. It will be usefull

Comment: @Esailija Does IE really report false? I didn't know that.

Comment: @ Esailija, what is the NonFragile solution ?

Comment: You are asking the browser to serialize DOM again into html, it is highly unlikely it will be exactly the same as the initial html the dom was parsed from. In ie7, the reported html is different from ie8 which is different from ie9

Comment: For example, if we say `var num = 9.00000000`, it's impossible to get those zeroes back. `num.toString()` will give `"9"`.

Comment: `.html()` just calls innerHTML, which remains the same across all browsers IMO.

Comment: @ Esailija, do you agree about innerHTML ?

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon How can that be an `IMO`? It's easy to test it's not the case. See: http://jsfiddle.net/zheT3/ Gives unique result for each IE7, IE8 and IE9.

Comment: I see your point. IE6 seems to be the one displaying really weird results.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please tell me if I missed something though.

Comment: Seems fine to me now (although I don't understand the question in the first place ;D). Out of curiosity, what did you get in IE6? lol

Comment: I got the `IMG` tag in caps, and the entire absolute path of the `img src`.
`<IMG src="http://fiddle.jshell.net/.../check_01.png">`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#user_status").find('img').attr('src','check_01.png'))
```

Comment: What is the point of putting this into an `if`? It always evaluates to `true`